# If $a_{n}>0$ and $\sum a_{n}$ converges, does $\sum a_{n}^{1- \frac{1}{\sqrt{ n }}}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given that $a_n >0$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, how can I judge if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}^{1- \frac{1}{\sqrt{ n }}}$ converges?

I already know that for any $s\ge 1$, given the conditions $\sum a_n^s$ also converges. and for any $0<s<1$, let $a_n= n^{-s^{-1}}$ then $\sum a_n$ converges but $\sum a_n^s$ diverges. But those arguments don't apply to $1- \frac{1}{\sqrt n}$.

Comment: yes it smaller than converge value of summation of a_n and increasing function

Comment: @maarhybrid For most of the $a_n$, we have $a_n<a_n^{1-\sqrt n}$.

Comment: @vishalnaakar That is a nice example. You can post it as  an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my proof, if there are some mistakes, please tell me! Thanks very much!

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, we can get $a_n\to0$, so WLG we can suppose $0<a_n<1,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Consider the sum of the following $2k+1$ terms:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1}a_{n}^{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}
\leq&\sum_{n=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1}a_{n}^{1-\frac{1}{k}}\\
=&\sum_{n=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1}\sqrt[k]{\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}2a_n\cdots2a_n}\\
\leq&\sum_{n=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1}\left(\frac{1}{k\cdot2^{k-1}}+\frac{2(k-1)}{k}a_n\right)\quad \text{(by AM-GM inequality)}\\
=&\frac{2k+1}{k}\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}+\frac{2(k-1)}{k}\sum_{n=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1}a_n\\
<&\frac{3}{2^{k-1}}+2\sum_{n=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1}a_n.
\end{align}
So
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}^{1- \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k^2}^{(k+1)^2-1}a_{n}^{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}
<\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{3}{2^{k-1}}+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n<\infty.$$